# model.cuda() in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

If I call `model.cuda()` in pytorch where model is a subclass of `nn.Module`, and say if I have four GPUs, how it will utilize the four GPUs and how do I know which GPUs that are using?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a custom module derived from `nn.Module` after `model.cuda()` all model parameters, (`model.parameters()` iterator can show you these) will end on your cuda.

To check where are your parameters just print them (cuda:0) in my case:

```
class M(nn.Module):
    'custom module'
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin = nn.Linear(784, 10)

m = M()
m.cuda()
for _ in m.parameters():
    print(_)

# Parameter containing:
# tensor([[-0.0201,  0.0282, -0.0258,  ...,  0.0056,  0.0146,  0.0220],
#         [ 0.0098, -0.0264,  0.0283,  ...,  0.0286, -0.0052,  0.0007],
#         [-0.0036, -0.0045, -0.0227,  ..., -0.0048, -0.0003, -0.0330],
#         ...,
#         [ 0.0217, -0.0008,  0.0029,  ..., -0.0213,  0.0005,  0.0050],
#         [-0.0050,  0.0320,  0.0013,  ..., -0.0057, -0.0213,  0.0045],
#         [-0.0302,  0.0315,  0.0356,  ...,  0.0259,  0.0166, -0.0114]],
#        device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
# Parameter containing:
# tensor([-0.0027, -0.0353, -0.0349, -0.0236, -0.0230,  0.0176, -0.0156,  0.0037,
#          0.0222, -0.0332], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

You can also specify the device like this:

```
m.cuda('cuda:0')
```

With `torch.cuda.device_count()` you may check how many devices you have.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [prosti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852561/10886420) to split your computations among multiple GPUs you should use [`torch.nn.DataParallel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852561/10886420) or `DistributedDataParallel`.